# evaluate awk and keep lines

Tags: awk, hp-ux

I have txt file with data inside like:

```
string1,string2,string3,string4,string5
```

I want to assign awk for string3 to a variable dc like:

```
dc=$(awk -F',' '{print $3}' file)
```

But then when I evaluate dc with $dc to see output per line, not space separated.

Now with: echo $dc, I see:

```
string3 string3 string3 string3 string3 string3 string3
```

I want to see:

```
string3
string3
string3
string3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with awk, you just need quotes around `$dc`:

```
$ cat x
a
b
c

$ dc=$(cat x)

$ echo $dc
a b c

$ echo "$dc"
a
b
c
```

The way I understand it is, without the quotes, you're giving `echo` a list of arguments separated by whitespace (in other words, none of those arguments include a newline). With the quotes, you're giving `echo` a single argument, which is a string that itself includes the newlines.